# Cookies and http requests

Tags: python, http, cookies, request

I have this [url](http://migueldvl.com/heya/login/tests2.php), the content are produced in this way (php, it's supose to generate a random cookie on every request):

```
setcookie('token', md5(time()), time()+99999);
if(isset($_COOKIE['token'])) {
    echo 'Cookie: ' .$_COOKIE['token'];
    die();
}
echo 'Cookie not set yet';
```

As you can see, the cookie changes on every reload/refresh of the page. Now i have a python (python3) script with three completely independent from each other requests:

```
import requests

def get_req_data(req):
    print('\n\ntoken: ', req.cookies['token'])
    print('headers we sent: ', req.request.headers)
    print('headers server sent back: ', req.headers)

url = 'http://migueldvl.com/heya/login/tests2.php'
headers = {
    "User-agent" : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1',
    "Referer": 'https://www.google.com'
}

req1 = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
get_req_data(req1)

req2 = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
get_req_data(req2)

req3 = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
get_req_data(req3)
```

How can be that we sometimes have the same cookie in diferent requests? If clearly it's program to change on every request?

If we:

```
import time
```

and add a

```
time.sleep(1) # wait one second before the next request
```

between requests, the cookie change all the time, this is the right and expected behaviour, but my question is why do we need this (`time.sleep(1)`) to be certain of the changing cookie? Wouldn't different requests be enough?

Comment: You  try take cookie from future ? Server very upset to you ! And additional question : `How will be sure all established connection are finished ?`

Comment: No, that (`time()+99999`) is the expiration date of the cookie @dsgdfg

Comment: Set cookie not  for only some hash values or etc, `which alive` and server detect you `impossible can send me query   every on 100ms `.

Comment: "impossible can send me query every on 100ms" really? How do you know? and how do facebook/google do it (999999 cookies in 100ms)?

Comment: Google and facebook always reject (or give a captcha )you if knowing `request source is a computer`.. Search for low level security (`this is a answer`).

Comment: A question (lol not only one) : `which user can press button on 100ms ?`. I delete all my comment cos `this is not legal action !`

Comment: Indeed, but as you can see the 'internet' doesn't need a browser to work, and to be scraped @dsgdfg